# selecting only few colums from a table through hibernate criteria api

Tags: hibernate, criteria

I need to fetch selected columns of a table from database through hibernate criteria , 
I have already got the pojo corresponding to the table and it mapping is done ,
i am writing the criteria in the below format but it
is not working fine as upon debuging and inspecting i can see that the list is empty
please advise what is wroing in the below quoery

```
public List<abc> Extractingioapublishfor()
        {
            Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(abc.class);

            criteria.setProjection( Projections.projectionList().add(Projections.property("rId;")));
            criteria.setProjection( Projections.projectionList().add(Projections.property("tId")));
            criteria.setProjection( Projections.projectionList().add(Projections.property("ld")));
            return criteria.list();
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, there is a **';'** in the first column name. That might be the reason it is not getting results.
Secondly, all projections should be added to the same projection list like below;

```
public List<abc> Extractingioapublishfor()
        {
            Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(abc.class);

            criteria.setProjection( Projections.projectionList().add(Projections.property("rId"))
 .add(Projections.property("tId")).add(Projections.property("ld")));
            return criteria.list();
        }
```